Import Error: cannot import 'SlashCommand' from 'discord.app_commands'
Here is my code:
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.app_commands import SlashCommand
from discord import Client, Intents

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True

client = Client(intents=intents)

mute_command = SlashCommand(client, name="mute", description="Mutes a member for a specific reason.")

@mute_command.callback
async def mute(ctx: Interaction, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    # Check if user has permission to mute
    if not ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_roles:
        await ctx.send("You don't have permissions to mute members!")
        return

    # Check if bot can mute the member (consider bot hierarchy and roles)
    if member.top_role >= ctx.me.top_role:
        await ctx.send("I can't mute users with higher or equal roles!")
        return

    # Get the role for muted members (create one if it doesn't exist)
    muted_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if not muted_role:
        muted_role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Muted")
        await muted_role.edit(permissions=discord.Permissions(speak=False))  # Remove speak permission

    # Mute the member by adding the muted role
    await member.add_roles(muted_role, reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been muted!")

    # Optional: Send a direct message to the muted user (with reason)
    if reason:
        await member.send(f"You have been muted in {ctx.guild.name} for: {reason}")
    else:
        await member.send(f"You have been muted in {ctx.guild.name}.")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.application_command.sync()  # Use client.application_command

    # This function runs when the bot is ready
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user} (ID: {client.user.id})')

# I swapped out "MY_TOKEN" for my bot token
client.run("MY_TOKEN")

I was trying to make a basic moderation bot including slash commands such as /mute, /timeout and /ban. However, every time I tried to run the code it said I couldn't import the SlashCommand from discord.app_commands. I have tried and failed the following methods of debugging:

Updating to Python 3.12.3
Updating, reinstalling and force reinstalling Discord.py 2.3.2
Using discord_py_slash_command
Using discord.interactions module


This is not how you make slash (app) commands using discord.py. In discord.py, there is a app_commands.CommandTree which holds all your application commands. If you're using a commands.Bot instance, a tree will be automatically created for you and it will be accessible through Bot.tree. An example of a slash command in discord.py:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@bot.tree.command()
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction): # Keep in the mind this takes a `discord.Interaction` and not `commands.Context`
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello!")

bot.run("<TOKEN>")

Keep in mind that you need to sync the application commands to discord using CommandTree.sync, this is a coroutine. This can be done using a regular text command as syncing in on_ready is not recommended.
An example of a sync command:
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner() # So only you can use this
async def sync(ctx: commands.Context):
    commands = await bot.tree.sync()
    await ctx.send(f"Synced {len(commands)} commands.")

This command can be customized to your needs.
Some useful resources:

Documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#application-commands
A proper sync command with more features: https://about.abstractumbra.dev/discord.py/2023/01/29/sync-command-example.html
Examples: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples/app_commands

